# Can .apk file contain another third party .apk file in its assets directory while uploading to googleplay

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-assets

I have created an app that contains another third party .apk in its assets directory.
 And I want to know that if i upload my app to Google play .
 Is there any problem something like ".apk file can not contain another .apk file" or etc.

I have installed the third party app programmatically from my assets folder.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File
                (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/com.ayansoft.androphp-1.2.0-free-eccb-www.apkhere.com.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
```